# How does it work in Python? "a = a, b = b, a"

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, tuples

```
a = 10
b = 20

print(a, b)  # 10, 20
a = a, b = b, a  # How does it work?
print(a, b)  # 20, 10... Why?
```

It is obvious that "a, b = b, a" will swap variables. But what does "a =" do in this case and why doesn't it affect the output?

```
a = 10
b = 20

print(a, b)  # 10, 20

# a = a, b = b, a
a, b = b, a
a = a, b

print(a, b)  # (20, 10) 10
```

Comment: The RHS is evaluated first and a, b is the Tuple (20, 10) after the swap. The name on the LHS **a**  is then assigned to this object so print(a) shows (20,10). See [link](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html) for a well-known summary of how values and names work in Python.

Answer (score 3):

using the `dis` module to disassemble the code in python 3.11 you get this.

```
def foo():
    a = 10
    b = 20
    a = a, b = b, a

import dis
dis.dis(foo)
```

```
10 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
12 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
14 BUILD_TUPLE              2
16 COPY                     1
18 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
20 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
24 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
26 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
```

it first stores (b,a) into a, then unpacks the "old value" of (b,a) into (a,b) thus overwriting a to be just b instead of a tuple, essentially doing

```
temp = b,a
a = temp
a,b = temp
```

i don't think this is proper python, and no one should ever write code like that, and i wouldn't be surprised if this behavior changed in the future.

Comment: See also [the Python language reference, section 7.2](https://docs.python.org/3.12/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements): "An assignment statement evaluates the expression list (remember that this can be a single expression or a comma-separated list, the latter yielding a tuple) and assigns the single resulting object to each of the target lists, **from left to right**." (Emphasis mine)

Comment: @Jasmijn seems to me like it is doing the outer assignment first `(a = b,a)` then the inner one `(a,b = b,a)`, i don't think this behavior is safe to rely on.

Comment: It's as safe to rely on as anything described in the documentation. In the case of `a = a, b = b, a`, first `(b, a)` is evaluated (let's call it `temp`), then `a = temp`, and then `a, b = temp`, which corresponds to the behaviour you saw in the `dis.dis` output. You can also see it in the grammar: `a` and `a, b` both get parsed as `target_list`, while `b, a` gets parsed as `starred_expression`.